# AttributeError: 'torch.FloatTensor' object has no attribute 'item'

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

Here are the codes：

```
    from __future__ import print_function
    from itertools import count

    import torch 
    import torch.autograd
    import torch.nn.functional as F

    POLY_DEGREE = 4
    W_target = torch.randn(POLY_DEGREE, 1) * 5
    b_target = torch.randn(1) * 5


    def make_features(x):
        x = x.unsqueeze(1)
        return torch.cat([x ** i for i in range(1, POLY_DEGREE+1)], 1)


    def f(x):
        return x.mm(W_target) + b_target.item()
```

This resulted in the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'torch.FloatTensor' object has no attribute 'item'
```

How can I solve this please?

Comment: I ran this code about 20 days ago and it didn't occur this issue at that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `item()` is new from PyTorch `0.4.0`. When using earlier versions of PyTorch you will get this error. 
So you can upgrade your PyTorch version your to solve this.

Edit:

I got through your example again. What do you want archive with `item()`?
In your case `item()` should just give you the (python) float value in the tensor.
Why do you want to use this? You can just leave out `item()`.

So:

```
def f(x):
    return x.mm(W_target) + b_target
```

instead of:

```
def f(x):
    return x.mm(W_target) + b_target.item()
```

This should work for you, in PyTorch 0.4.0 there is not difference. It is also more efficient to leave out `item()`.

Comment: Thanks, but what's the data attribute exactly means?